How to redirect post-404page to 404 page in Avada
I'm in staging and cannot provide a link.
Using Avada theme which suggests to create a custom 404 layout, which will not work for how I want it to look.
In Avada the 404.php shows div id="post-404page" yet cannot locate that post. Also cannot find a 404 template anywhere in the theme. Built a custom 404 page I want to use. Tried different variations of ErrorDocument and Redirect in .htaccess with no success.
What would be the best way to redirect the post-404page to page url? Thanks!
